# Need help understanding locking in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, locking

I'm having some trouble understanding the basic concepts of locking in a multi-user / web application.
When a user gets authorized by our federation, he'll return with a username claim, which we'll then use to retrieve some extra info about him like so:

```
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
if(!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(CustomClaims.UserId)) //If not set, retrieve it from dataBase
{
   //This can take some time
   var userId = retrieveUserId(claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)); 
   //Because the previous call could take some time, it's possible we add the claim multiple time during concurrent requests
   claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaims.UserId, userId));
}
```

As indicated in the code, having duplicate claims isn't really what I'm looking for, so I thought I'd lock everything around the check whether the claim exists or not:

```
private static readonly object _authorizeLock = new object();
...
lock(_authorizeLock)
{
   if(!claimsIdentity.HasClaim(CustomClaims.UserId)) //If not set, retrieve it from dataBase
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

However, this doesn't feel right. Wouldn't this lock be for **all** incoming requests? This would mean that even authorized users would still have to "wait", even though their info has already been retrieved.

Does anybody have an idea how I could best deal with this?

Comment: You are right to be suspicious. Locks are to be avoided in a web-app. You probably need a high-availability solution which usually means multiple IIS'es. This lock is not shareable across the cluster.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c5kehkcz.aspx kinda says it all... "The lock keyword ensures that one thread does not enter a critical section of code while another thread is in the critical section. If another thread tries to enter a locked code, it will wait, block, until the object is released." It depends on where you are putting the check, if you did it on every page load then yeah, it will affect all users for all requests. The real question here is why are you locking not just "so I thought I'd lock everything", what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's what I feared... Are there any decent sollutions to this besides locking, then?  @PaulZahra I'm not sure I understand the question in your edit.

Comment: Nevermind my Q... have a read of this http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:
Get over it and live with duplicate entries.

Answer 2:
If you have sessions turned on you get implicit locking between requests from the same user (session) by accessing the session storage. Simply add a dummy

```
Session["TRIGGER_SESSION_LOCKING_DUMMY"] = true
```

Answer 3:
Implement some custom locking on an object indexed by your Identity. Something like this

```
lock(threadSafeStaticDictionary[User.Identity.Name]) { ... }
```

Answer 4: 
Lock on the Identity object directly (which should be shared since you get duplicates) (though it is not recommended)

```
lock(User.Identity)
```